# Creating User and Password in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I tried this syntax

```
CREATE USER username IDENTIFIED BY Password;
```

and it doesn't work.

This error is shown:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BY'.

I don't know if the syntax is wrong or there's a proper and easier syntax in SQL Server for creating a user.

Comment: The syntax above is for Oracle only, what is the syntax for MSSql?

Comment: Do you have an issue looking up the documentation?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documentation: [CREATE USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql)

Here is one way to create a LOGIN and USER (these are two different things):

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [newbiee] WITH PASSWORD=N'asdfl@##@$kljaio234234bb' MUST_CHANGE
     , DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO

USE [test]
GO
CREATE USER [newbiee] FOR LOGIN [newbiee] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create a regular SQL Server user and login with permission to read, write and delete data:

```sql
USE [master]
CREATE LOGIN [username] WITH PASSWORD = N'long-password-123'

USE [database]
CREATE USER [username] FOR LOGIN [username]
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE TO [username]
```